# After successfully running an if/else statement, my ViewBag's orginal content seems "embedded"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

So I'm trying to mimick a isitchristmas.com with a holiday from my country. I'm using a HomeController do this and have found an answer to most of my questions on here already.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Vars
        DateTime datumvandaag = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime sinterklaasdatum = DateTime.Parse("06/12/2013");

        //If Else
        if (datumvandaag.Date==sinterklaasdatum.Date)
        {
            ViewBag.Info = "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Info = "no"
        }
        //Show
        return View();
```

My problem is that once I tried to change "yes" and "no", it just stuck with those original values. I tried saving, restarting Visual Studio, even if I delete the code it still returns the original result. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: Maybe your browser is caching something? Try incognito mode/private mode maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The usual cause for problems like this is remnant build fragments. try cleaning your solution in VS 2013 and then rebuilding it.